# What are the pitfalls of adding a corporate eSIM to an unmanaged employee device in lieu of land-line phones?

Tags: mobile, simcard

Instead of having a landline at each employee's desk, allow them to add an eSIM to a compatible personal cell phone. (If possible, disable SMS for the added eSIM so it is acting as a replacement for the desk phone.)

Unmanaged phones are often used for MS365 and MFA already.

What MUST be considered when adding a company-owned eSIM tech to a personal phone?

If you're the attacker, what technical capabilities to do harm do you gain if you own one of these user's phones? (As opposed to owning a regular email user's unmanaged device, logging into email and phishing if you get their password and can trick UEBA.) Two that come to my mind easily are 1. SMS phishing with the newly-added business number (which I try to address above), and 2. easier impersonations (vishing).